# Width and height of something to be used in a TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, width

In the code below, I would like to calculate the shifts using the width and the height of `{\tiny any integer}`. My need is to automatically adjust the width and the height of the decorating red box, and also to position the red text at the good place.

[image]

What is the easiest way to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

% Need: use of the width and the height of the #3 argument
% to calculate the good value instead of the +/- 8pt.
%
% yshift and xshift not have to be equal.
\newcommand\stepit[3]{
    \node[red] 
        at ($([shift={(-8pt,-8pt)}] #1-|#2)!.5!(#1-|#2)$) 
        {\tiny #3};

    \draw[red] 
        ([xshift=-8pt] #1-|#2) 
        --
        ([shift={(-8pt,-1.75ex)}] #1-|#2)
        --
        ([yshift=-1.75ex] #1-|#2);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l*{4}{|w{c}{2.5cm}@{}}@{\hspace{-1pt}}}
            & Magie
            & Théâtre
            & Photo
            & Total \\
    \hline
    Adultes & 123
            & 
            & 
            &  \\
    \hline
    Enfants & 
            & 
            & Value
            &  \\
    \hline
    Total   & 
            &
            &
            & Total
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \stepit{2}{3}{1234}
        \stepit{4}{4}{56}
        \stepit{2}{4}{7}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: PGFmath has `height("\tiny 1234")` and `depth` and `width`. But TikZ also has a better placement for nodes: `\node[red, inner sep=0, below left, append after command={(\tikzlastnode.north west) edge[to path={|-(\tikzlastnode.south east)},red]()}] at (2-|3) {\tiny 1234};` `below left` is `anchor=north east` and the `append after command` is just a separate path that references the node without you having to explicitly name it. Adjust inner sep for vertical and horizontal padding.

Comment: Give me some of your knowledge... What an idiot I am, this has just been done. :-) Thanks again, and I promise I'll stop here for today.

Comment: `\newcommand\stepit[3]{\node[red, inner sep=2pt, below left, append after command = {(\tikzlastnode.north west) edge[to path={|-(\tikzlastnode.south east)},red]()}] at ($(#1-|#2)!.5!(#1-|#2)$) {\tiny #3};}` does a good job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are PGFMath functions available that measure the dimensions of text, namely

- `height("\tiny 1234")`,
- `depth("\tiny 1234")` and
- `width("\tiny 1234")`

a node already does that for you (it measures the `\ht`, `\dp` and `\wd` of the box with its contents) to create the rectangle around it.

It padds this box with the values of `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` which are, by default, .3333em, i.e. a font and font-size dependent value.

Instead of using `\tiny 1234` or `font = \tiny`, I'm using [`node font = \tiny`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/node:font) which also applies the `\tiny` font to these values which in my opinion already creates a visually nice output.

This node is placed with its north east corner/anchor at the cross point `(#1-|#2)`.

Instead of naming this node and using its name to (re)draw the border I've chose to use `append after command` which appends a path specification after the node where `\tikzlastnode` is available for referencing this node.
All nodes are always named if not by the user (via `name` or the `()` syntax). It gets an internal name `tikz@f@<number>` which allows you to use `\tikzlastnode` without having to think about any name that might overwrite another one. Though, this is here not a problem because you can give them all the same name since you don't need to reference them anymore after `\stepit`.

If you don't use `outer sep = 0pt` the resulting line wouldn't lie exactly on top of the node's border were it drawn.

Here's a close look at the same example with a drawn node and an `ultra thick` line width.
Left: `outer sep = .5\pgflinewidth` (default)
Right: `outer sep = 0pt`:
[image][image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[multi=NiceTabular]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

% Need: use of the width and the height of the #3 argument
% to calculate the good value instead of the +/- 8pt.
%
% yshift and xshift not have to be equal.
\newcommand\stepit[3]{
  \draw[
    shorten >=+.5\pgflinewidth,
    shorten <=+.5\pgflinewidth,
    red]
   node[
     node font=\tiny,
     anchor=north east,
     outer sep=+0pt,
     append after command={
       (\tikzlastnode.north west) |- (\tikzlastnode.south east)
     }] at (#1-|#2) {#3};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l*{4}{|w{c}{2.5cm}@{}}@{\hspace{-1pt}}}
            & Magie
            & Théâtre
            & Photo
            & Total \\
    \hline
    Adultes & 123
            & 
            & 
            &  \\
    \hline
    Enfants & 
            & 
            & Value
            &  \\
    \hline
    Total   & 
            &
            &
            & Total
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \stepit{2}{3}{1234}
        \stepit{4}{4}{56}
        \stepit{2}{4}{7}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the code and the explanations.